# Node JS Application not taking Values from postman

Tags: node.js, api, express, postman, mern

I wrote two node js applications, they are fetching data properly but they are not taking post values 1st applications is this [TinderClone](https://github.com/Shaxadhere/tinder-clone/tree/master/tinder-backend) this is just an api with no frontend i am posting data from postman and it is returning auto generated id but not the data i am posting,

Other application i cloned from github, it has proper frontend with working CRUD, but when i tried to post values from postman it wont take any values it will just add record in database with null values, so is there anything wrong im doing on postman? cause it is still working if i post data with the form on its frontend the application url is [MernCRUD](https://github.com/Shaxadhere/MernCRUD)

Postman Screenshots:
[posting data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMqoW.png),
[fetching data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IVaj.png)

Code:

```
//Cards Schema (Cards.js)
import mongoose from 'mongoose'

const cardSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    imgUrl: String
})

export default mongoose.model('cards', cardSchema)

//Posting Data (Server.js)
app.post('/tinder/cards', (req, res) => {
const dbCard = req.body;

   Cards.create(dbCard, (err, data) => {
       if(err){
          res.status(500).send(err)
       }
       else{
          res.status(201).send(data)
       }
   })
})

//Fetching Data
app.get('/tinder/cards', (req, res) => {
   Cards.find((err, data) => {
       if(err){
          res.status(500).send(error);
       }
       else{
          res.status(200).send(data);
       }
   });
});
```

Comment: please add postman screenshots

Comment: i have added screenshot and code please can u check now

Comment: you should pass the `content-type` `application/json`  in your request, can you check what your api receive

Comment: Thank you so much the "content-type" - "application/json" solved it, thank you so muchh jskdajklsad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

in postman you don't have to add content type manually . You should select json from the drop down and it will add content type by default. **

### Now you have text in your raw dropdown change to json .

**